# Deeplinking to youtube content on Samsung TV (Tizen)

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, samsung

Could you please provide us with instructions for deep linking on youtube from other application on Samsung TV? For example, we want to launch youtube and open a specific channel on youtube from our application. Is this possible? And how we can do it? (We've already managed to open youtube but only homepage).

Comment: Could you share us the current code you achieved to reach to open YouTube homepage ? I have doubts that `youtube-api*` tags are relevant, you should mainly look for `samsung`, `samsung-smart-tv` and `tizen`. You can search next time relevant tags by using https://stackoverflow.com/tags. It seems that you are just looking to open an URL, that's not really specific to YouTube but you already achieved to open an URL it seems... So please clarify this point.

Comment: Hello @BenjaminLoison, I already wrote Tizen support, and they answered that I should ask youtube developers regarding deep linking the youtube app on tv. This is the code for launch yt app ``tizen.application.launch('9Ur5IzDKqV.TizenYouTube', arg => { Log.e('samsung.js', 'openExternalApplication', The app is launched, args: ${arg}) }, error => { Log.e('samsung.js', 'openExternalApplication', Failed to launch the app ${error}) } )``

Comment: Kind reminder: you don't have added the suggested tags to your question.