# Launching AppStore from Samsung Tizen TV App

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I'm trying to implement a button in Javascript based Tizen TV application. Upon clicking the button it should open App Store page of another application.

I'm referring to these documents:
https://developer.tizen.org/sites/default/files/documentation/tizen2.3_deep_linking_guide_v1.0.pdf
https://developer.tizen.org/ko/community/tip-tech/linking-your-application?langredirect=1
[Deeplinking to youtube content on Samsung TV (Tizen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72018119/deeplinking-to-youtube-content-on-samsung-tv-tizen)

I have added the following privileges in config.xml

```
  <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/>
  <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/appmanager.launch"/>
```

window.tizen is returning the following object

```
{"BundleValueType":{"STRING":"STRING","STRING_ARRAY":"STRING_ARRAY","BYTES":"BYTES","BYTES_ARRAY":"BYTES_ARRAY"},"cordova":{"file":{},"globalization":{}},"tvinputdevice":{},"systeminfo":{},"account":{},"alarm":{"PERIOD_MINUTE":60,"PERIOD_HOUR":3600,"PERIOD_DAY":86400,"PERIOD_WEEK":604800},"application":{},"archive":{},"filesystem":{"maxNameLength":255,"maxPathLength":4096},"content":{},"datacontrol":{},"download":{},"exif":{},"iotcon":{"deviceName":""},"keymanager":{},"mediacontroller":{},"mediakey":{},"messageport":{},"package":{},"push":{},"time":{},"tvaudiocontrol":{},"tvchannel":{},"tvdisplaycontrol":{},"tvinfo":{},"tvwindow":{},"voicecontrol":{},"websetting":{}}
```

Here window.tizen.application is an empty object

But we need to get `window.tizen.application.launch` OR `window.tizen.applciation.launchAppControl` to implement this functionality (as per above documents)

Does anyone have any idea why it's not available?